# Unable to know the reason for the response "This tracking number cannot be found. Please check the number or contact the sender"

Tags: response, fedex

I am getting a response "This tracking number cannot be found. Please check the number or contact the sender.", which is present in this object.
when I execute a php code to get tracking-id(781193603730) status data got from Fedex. But when I try to check the status of tracking id by loging into their portal I am able to get response. I need help on this, please help. Response object  =>

stdClass Object
(
    [HighestSeverity] => SUCCESS
    [Notifications] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Severity] => SUCCESS
            [Source] => trck
            [Code] => 0
            [Message] => Request was successfully processed.
            [LocalizedMessage] => Request was successfully processed.
        )

```
[TransactionDetail] => stdClass Object
    (
        [CustomerTransactionId] => *** Track Request using PHP ***
    )

[Version] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ServiceId] => trck
        [Major] => 16
        [Intermediate] => 0
        [Minor] => 0
    )

[CompletedTrackDetails] => stdClass Object
    (
        [HighestSeverity] => SUCCESS
        [Notifications] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Severity] => SUCCESS
                [Source] => trck
                [Code] => 0
                [Message] => Request was successfully processed.
                [LocalizedMessage] => Request was successfully processed.
            )

        [DuplicateWaybill] => 
        [MoreData] => 
        [TrackDetailsCount] => 0
        [TrackDetails] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Notification] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Severity] => ERROR
                        [Source] => trck
                        [Code] => 9040
                        [Message] => This tracking number cannot be found. Please check the number or contact the sender.
                        [LocalizedMessage] => This tracking number cannot be found. Please check the number or contact the sender.
                    )

                [TrackingNumber] => 781193603730
                [StatusDetail] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Location] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Residential] => 
                            )

                    )

                [PackageSequenceNumber] => 0
                [PackageCount] => 0
                [DeliveryAttempts] => 0
                [TotalUniqueAddressCountInConsolidation] => 0
                [DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Option] => INDIRECT_SIGNATURE_RELEASE
                                [Eligibility] => INELIGIBLE
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Option] => REDIRECT_TO_HOLD_AT_LOCATION
                                [Eligibility] => INELIGIBLE
                            )

                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Option] => REROUTE
                                [Eligibility] => INELIGIBLE
                            )

                        [3] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Option] => RESCHEDULE
                                [Eligibility] => INELIGIBLE
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the fedex tracking id that I was testing was real, and the credentials that I was using for fedex tracking api were of test/sandbox type not production.